# How to integrate Gigya with e-commerce?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, gigya

Im trying to integrate the Customer Data Cloud (Gigya) with Hybris 1905, Where I already installed the gigyaAddon, and gigyabackoffice for the project using the Gigya Documentation. When in the tutorial they open the backoffice it has more options than my backoffice, like Customer Data cloud (Gigya) users or Customer data cloud (Gigya) Raas Configuration. Did I miss something, should I install magento to get those filds, Also When I give the information and press Next I get the following error: "Could not resolve qualifier [gigya Global Advanced]", Why is this happenning ? Thanks for the help.

UPDATE: 
When Installing following the SAP tutorial, I found that they told you to configure a session managment, but Im not getting that field with backoffice.... Is that neccesarily to create a connection with Gigya?, Do I have a listener for login events out of the box that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

For support of SAP Commerce Cloud versions 1811 and above (e.g., 1905), use the native connector that is built-in to SAP Commerce Cloud, for additional information see: https://help.sap.com/viewer/50c996852b32456c96d3161a95544cdb/1811/en-US/4fc06a3539a940e6b707c0c543d44053.html

You should not be installing the stand-alone GConnector for use with that version of Hybris/Commerce Cloud.

Comment: When Installing following the SAP tutorial, I found that they told you to configure a session managment, but Im not getting that field with backoffice.... Is that neccesarily to create a connection with Gigya?, Do I have a listener for login events out of the box that I can use?